# combine table rows if user id is same in foreach loop laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have 3 tables

> **User**, **Orders**, **Extra Orders**

and I have used the hasMany method to get the data from tables. When data is inserted in the Extra Orders table having the user id and order id. but when two or three order are of same user id then it should club or combine all the extra orders in same card one by one. like https://prnt.sc/panfhi
but in my case, every row is having a different card. like https://prnt.sc/panga8 and my data is extracting as follows https://prnt.sc/panh0n

kindly advice the solution.

I have tried different methods of foreach loops but it's not working

getting the data from tables.

```
class GeneralController extends Controller {
    public function orderReceived() { 
         $extra_orders = ExtraOrders::with(['user','orders'])->get(); 
          dd($extra_orders->toArray());`enter code here`
     }
}
```

Comment: Please, don's post screenshots, but exact test data and desired output in terms of php. Also provide the code you tried to achieve this.

Comment: class GeneralController extends Controller
{
    public function orderReceived()
    { 

     $extra_orders = ExtraOrders::with(['user','orders'])->get();
     
     return view('pages.order_received',compact('extra_orders'));
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

check your relation function order
Order need to be **Hasmany Relationship**